Code for android devices that automatically deletes all photos (for personal use)
I want to ask for help in reviewing the code, since I'm not sure if there's any issue with the code below. Also wanted to ask if this code removes only photos or videos and downloaded media as well.
import android.Manifest
import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Request permission to access external storage
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
        } else {
            // If permission is already granted, start deletion
            deleteAllPhotos()
        }
    }

    // Handle the permission request result
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted, start deletion
            deleteAllPhotos()
        } else {
            // Permission denied, close the app or handle accordingly
            finish()
        }
    }

    // Function to delete all photos
    private fun deleteAllPhotos() {
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null)

        cursor?.use {
            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
                contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)
            }
        }

        // Once deletion is done, close the app
        finish()
    }
}



Please take the [tour] and read [ask].
